# Submitting a job to Kubernetes cluster using Spark-submit

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am trying to save spark-submit (Kubernetes) logs in S3 and I am getting S3 authentication errors.
Can any-one please help me with it.

```sh
spark-submit\
    --master k8s://https://kubernetes.cluster.svc\
    --deploy-mode cluster\
    --name spark-p1\
    --driver-memory 8g\
    --executor-memory 10g\
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi\
    --conf spark.executor.instances=2\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-py:v3.1.2.1\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=https://<s3endpoint>\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=id\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=password\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true\
    --conf spark.eventLog.dir=s3a://bucket/folder/\
    --conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=s3a://bucket/folder/\
    --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=True\
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=tools\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-p1-driver\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark\
    local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py 10000
```

**Error:**

```
21/12/07 20:36:47 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-p1-77b0007d969cd3f4-driver-svc.tools.svc:4040                                                                              │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:47 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors                                                                                            │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:47 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down                                                                             │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:47 WARN ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)                                                              │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!                                                                                        │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared                                                                                                           │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped                                                                                                          │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped                                                                                                    │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!                                                                               │
│ 21/12/07 20:36:48 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext                                                                                                    │
│ Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                      │
│  File “/opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py”, line 29, in <module>                                                                                                   │
│   spark = SparkSession\                                                                                                                          │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py”, line 228, in getOrCreate                                                                                         │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py”, line 384, in getOrCreate                                                                                           │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py”, line 146, in __init__                                                                                             │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py”, line 209, in _do_init                                                                                             │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py”, line 321, in _initialize_context                                                                                       │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py”, line 1568, in __call__                                                                                       │
│  File “/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py”, line 326, in get_return_value                                                                                      │
│ py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.                                                                                │
│ : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://dev-hari/playground: getFileStatus on s3a://dev-hari/playground: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 16BE936C4FC1EB63; S │
│   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:230)                                                                                                │
│   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:151)                                                                                                │
│   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2198)                                                                                            │
│   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2163)                                                                                          │
│   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2102)                                                                                             │
│   at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.requireLogBaseDirAsDirectory(EventLogFileWriters.scala:77)                                                                             │
│   at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.start(EventLogFileWriters.scala:221)                                                                                     │
│   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:83)                                                                                         │
│   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:604)                                                                                                     │
│   at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)                                                                                             │
│   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)                                                                                       │
│   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)                                                                                       │
│   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)                                                                                     │
│   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)                                                                                                  │
│   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)                                                                                                     │
│   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)                                                                                                  │
│   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)                                                                                                                 │
│   at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)                                                                                            │
│   at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)                                                                                                 │
│   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)                                                                                                        │
│   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)                                                                                                            │
│ Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 16BE936C4FC1EB63; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null                     │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)                                                                                  │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)                                                                                   │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)                                                                                     │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)                                                                                       │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)                                                                                    │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)                                                                                        │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)                                                                                       │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)                                                                                  │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)                                                                                                │
│   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)                                                                                                │
│   at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4920)                                                                                               │
│   at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4866)
```

Comment: You will need to format that a bit better and give a bit more details like version, configuration, infrastructure… good luck!

Comment: Were you able to get past this @hari ?